# calling the results of each iteration in a series

Tags: r, data.table, iteration, series

I have run a loop and the results are saved in the list `com`. Now I have to call the results of each iteration ( # iterations=2000) and compute the mean of values as below:

```
l<-rbindlist(list(com[[1]], com[[2]], com[[3]],...com[[2000]]))[, .(values = mean(values)),
             by = variables][order(variables)].
```

I am a beginner in R. What would be the easy way of doing this?

Comment: If it is a list, just do `rbindlist(com)`

Comment: What exactly is the format of your com entries? Are they numerical vectors, as you wish to calculate a mean?

Comment: Do you need a `data.table` solution? Also, please show an example of one of the results in `com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you provide a data example, this will only be guesswork. I assume the results in your list `com` are numeric vectors. If not, this solution may not work.

This is base `R`, not `data.table`.

Example data:

```
set.seed(1)
com <- list(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), rnorm(100), rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
```

We bind the results together using `do.call`:

```
l <- do.call("rbind", com)
```

Now we use the vectorized `rowMeans`:

```
rowMeans(l)

> rowMeans(l)
[1]  0.10888737 -0.03780808  0.02967354  0.05160186 -0.03913424
```